# Excel Text to Column Equivalent in C# Datatable

Tags: c#, excel, csv, datatable

Although several `C# methods` in regards to the conversion of a `CSV` file to DataTable exist online, none of them seems to replicate `Excel - Convert Text to Columns`. To illustrate my point, suppose the following sample `CSV` is used:

```
" FIRst row DATA T"
;;
"Excel versus Csharp" ; ; ; ;
; "MA"; "10000"; "20000"; ; "400000";;; ;; ;;;

"SECOND REPORTING" 
"1"; "20"; ; "";"";"";"";"";"";"";
```

One is expecting (*ideally without the double `quotes` on the `string`*) to obtaining in the `DataTable`:

```
FIRst row DATA T


Excel versus Csharp
                 MA   10000   20000    40000  ...   

SECOND REPORTING
           1     20 ....
```

**Method** used:

```
public static DataTable CSVQuoteToDataTable(string   
csvFilePath)
    {
        DataTable csvData = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            string[] seps = { "\";", ";\"" };
            char[] quotes = { '\"', ' ' };
            string[] colFields = null;
            foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(csvFilePath)) % targets unfortunately the 1st row as column of the DataTable
            {
                var fields = line
                    .Split(seps, StringSplitOptions.None)
                    .Select(s => s.Trim(quotes).Replace("\\\"", "\""))
                    .ToArray();

                if (colFields == null)
                {
                    colFields = fields;
                    foreach (string column in colFields)
                    {
                        DataColumn datacolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                        datacolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(datacolumn);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (fields[i] == "")
                        {
                            fields[i] = null;
                        }
                    }
                    csvData.Rows.Add(fields);
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

       return csvData;
    }
```

Feedback on more *efficient or better* method would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I agree your format is CSV - firstly, it doesn't have a comma separately, but more importantly, it doesn't have the same number of columns in each line. CSV is for tabular data with the each record having the same number of fields.

Comment: the delimiter is `semicolon`, and you can obtain such kind of file in `notepad`, save as `. txt` then change the file extension from `.txt` to `CSV`. Thus you will end up with a `CSV` with semi colon delimiters. Indeed the file does not have the same number of columns in each line, making the task a bit challenging.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish most of what you desire with the Nuget extension LumenWorksCsvReader.  It will allow you to use a delimiter other than a comma and handle quotes (or not, if you choose).

https://www.nuget.org/packages/LumenWorksCsvReader/

The only problem I see is the variable number of columns, in which case you may have to handle that in your code -- determine the max number of columns and use that.  The package will throw an exception when you try to read outside the range, and as clumsy as it may seem, you can just include a try/catch for that.

Bare bones, but something like this should get you started.

```
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\cdh\foo.csv"))
{
    using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(sr, hasHeaders:false, delimiter:';', quote:'"'))
    {
        while (reader.ReadNextRecord())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxFieldCount; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    string val = reader[i];
                    // do something with 'val'
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```